# Android Studio 1.3 multidex error in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I can't build project properly after I updated my Android Studio to 1.3 version. I found in project gradle file error in line

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and it says

```
This support library should not use a lower version (1) than the targetSdkVersion (22)
```

but in my SDK folder i cant find higher version of multidex.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio 1.3 is not production ready at the moment (that's why it's on Canary channel). While it's fine to try it, switching permanently may be unwise due to many lurking bugs or issues. I'd recommend downgrading to 1.2. And I guess Android Studio team do not mind seeing bug reports based on your 1.3 experience [submitted here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry).

Comment: Yup that's what I ended up doing. Thank you.